# Validity of the proof of $F$ is a function iff $F^{-1}$ is single-rooted, where $F$ is a relation.

Tags: set-theory

I've constructed a proof for the following theorem:

> If $F$ is a relation then $F$ is a function iff $F^{-1}$ is single-rooted.

which is much shorter than what's presented in the book, *Daniel W. Cunningham. “Set Theory: A First Course.”*. However, I'm doubting that there may be some insidious bug in my proof that I fail to see (otherwise the author could've chosen it)?

Here's my proof:

$
\begin{align}
F^{-1}&=\{<y,x>:<x, y>\in F\}\text{ is single-rooted}\\
&\leftrightarrow (\forall x\in ran(F^{-1}))\exists!y(<y,x>\in F^{-1})\\
&\leftrightarrow(\forall x\in dom(F))\exists!y(<x,y>\in F) &ran(F^{-1})=dom(F)\text{ (*)}\\
&\leftrightarrow F\text{ is a function based on the definition.}
\end{align}
$

(*) The result that $ran(F^{-1})=dom(F)$ is proved earlier in the book already.

Comment: At first look, the proof looks fine to me. What's the gist of the proof given in the book?

Comment: The proof in the book uses the double bidirectional strategy, i.e prove $F\text{ is a function then }F^{-1}\text{ is single-rooted}$ and the reverse of it. I don't understand why the author didn't do it in just one go like my proof.

Comment: Well, if the proof is the same (is it?) but just done one direction at a time, I'd say the author did that for pedagogical reasons (which is really ironic right now).

Comment: The argument is the same indeed.